# Granting access with UnanimousBased AccessDecisionManager

Tags: spring-security

I was reading the Pro Spring Security book few days ago, and something was not clear to me about the access granting of **UnanimousBased AccessDecisionManager**. The author says:

> **UnanimousBased**
>   As you probably guessed, this access decision manager will grant access to the resource only if all the
>   configured voters vote in favor of allowing access to the resource. If any voter votes to deny the access, the
>   AccessDeniedException will be thrown. The “all abstain” case is handled the same way as with the other
>   implementations of AccessDecisionManager.

What will happen if all of the configured voters vote to allow access, except one who votes to abstain? Will the AccessDeniedException be thrown?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have written answer in your question only i.e If any voter(Even if one of them) votes to deny the access, the AccessDeniedException will be thrown.